# How to disable add permission in the Django's admin page when the choices drop down field doesn't contain any data?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I have a model which has a template_name field which is shown as drop down in django admin.

```
template_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=template_data, unique=True)
```

The `template_data` is getting populated from some other script.
The format of template_data is : `(('123', 'car'), ('456', 'bike'))`

This works fine when `template_data` has some values but when the `template_data` is an empty tuple, then I want to disable any add permission on admin page.

Currently when the redis is off, the add button is disabled but how to do the same when the `template_data` is an empty tuple?

Diasbled add permission when redis is off:

```
def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    is_redis = RedisCache.is_redis_available()
    if is_redis is not True:
        return False
    return True
```

`RedisCache.is_redis_available()`: Redis check is happening by calling `is_redis_available` func of `RadisCache` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why cannot you load template_data directly in the permission method?

```
def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    if not template_data:
        return False
    is_redis = RedisCache.is_redis_available()
    if is_redis is not True:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Actually I was doing like how you suggested but instead of checking the variable template_data, I was checking the model field template_id. 
But, your suggestion worked. Thanks a lot.